# Xamarin.Forms binding with data trigger - value not updating

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, datatrigger

I want to show the elapsed time on a video. I have a label with a format specifier like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding CurrentTime, StringFormat='{0:D3} seconds'}" />
```

This works, and I get a string like `053 seconds`. I want to show the text `Not playing` when the video is not playing, which I specify like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding CurrentTime, StringFormat='{0:D3} seconds'}">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsPlaying}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Not playing" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

This correctly displays `Not playing` when the video is not playing, but when it is, the label is stuck on `000 seconds` forever. What is going wrong?

#### Edit

The view looks like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyNamespace.VideoPage"
             x:Name="ThePage"
             BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=ThePage}">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding CurrentTime, StringFormat='{0:D3} seconds'}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Label.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsPlaying}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Not playing" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Label.Triggers>
        </Label>
        <!-- More stuff -->
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The code-behind looks like this:

```
public partial class VideoPage : ContentPage
{
    private int currentTime;

    public int CurrentTime
    {
        get { return currentTime; }
        set
        {
            currentTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool isPlaying;

    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get { return isPlaying; }
        set
        {
            isPlaying = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

#### Edit 2

With the help of Yuri's answer I fixed it with the following

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="PlayingStyle">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Not playing" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsPlaying}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding CurrentTime, StringFormat='{0:D3} seconds'}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<Label Style="{StaticResource PlayingStyle}" />
```

Comment: does the class you're binding to implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Jason When I do not have the trigger, the value is set correctly and updates.

Comment: What does your model or view model look like?

Comment: @Ethan2Pants I added the relevant parts

Comment: Not all parts. I don't see how "ThePage" is bound and OnPropertyChanged is called but where is the interface INotifyPropertyChanged is defined?

Comment: Hi @YuriS. The page is bound to itself `x:Name="ThePage" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=ThePage}"` and the `OnPropertyChanged()` method is defined by `ContentPage` so you can find that through object explorer.

Comment: so, your model is the page?

Comment: @YuriS yep. Great software architecture I know. Forget my lack of MVVM, that is not the problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xaml seems to be confused by two different types of bindings to text - one from trigger and another "direct" This is how it works:

```
   <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <Label.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding  IsPlaying}"  Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding CurrentTime, StringFormat='{0:D3} seconds'}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding  IsPlaying}"  Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Not playing" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
```

Thinking about option to give a "default" value to the label and do it as a child without style

```
    <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="Not playing">
        <Label.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding  IsPlaying}"  Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding CurrentTime, StringFormat='{0:D3} seconds'}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
```

Comment: You are half right. Your suggestion is fine in this case because there are only two possible values for boolean. If it was a number where I wanted a trigger for the value 0 and a setting for 'everything else' then your solution wouldn't work. My mistake, which you rightly pointed out, was to define the property directly while trying to override it with a trigger, which doesn't work. I have updated my answer with the final solution.

Comment: What I find really annoying in Xamarin is that I cannot define this particular style directly as a child of the label. For some reason it doesn't like having triggers in there. It works in Xaml on WPF. Just another one of those quirks I suppose.

Comment: @Steztric That's good using default setter. You are right it will work better in case of many options

Comment: @Steztric How about this? Edited my answer

Comment: It is actually a good practice to give (even empty string) default to the label

Comment: If that works then my mind is officially blown. In that case my assumption that a direct property setting doesn't automatically win over style / triggers. Forgive me but I'm not going to try it now, it is midnight in U.K.

Comment: I tried, it works :-) It is different default Binding or just straight set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150523/discussion-between-steztric-and-yuri-s).